# How to get Gmail-like/non-generic notifications with stock Android app?

Tags: notifications, stock-email-app

When I get a email notification from the stock Android Email app I just get a generic notification on the line of:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| [Mail icon] New email                    |
| 1 unread (Account Name)           18:34  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

How do I get email notifications with the sender and subject like with my Gmail app?

```
+------------------------------------------+
| [Mail icon] John Doe                     |
| Yet another boring meeting blah.. 18:34  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Is there some setting I've missed out on?

Has this been fixed in later versions of the Mail app (currently using 2.3.4)?

Saving the above, are there any third party apps, free or paid, available? (K-9 is no good was webDAV is disabled. My email account is on an Exchange server.)

My details:

I running Email.app version 2.3.4 on CyanogenMod 7.1.0 (Android 2.3.7) on a rooted phone.

I only have one (work) email account (an Exchange server) on the stock email app which I like to (and in any event have to) keep separate from my personal Gmail account.

**Edit**

Part of my question is what is other users experience of Android's stock email app like? Is it just my crappy phone or does everyone get the same notifications?